# CGo not compiling C files in same directory

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to create a CGO program with separate C source file in the same directory. As mentioned in the official Cgo docs, Cgo will compile all C files in the same directory but in this case, it is not compiling the C file. And later gives a linker error.

myTest.go

```
package main

/*

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "myTest.h"

*/
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func Print(s string) {
    cs := C.CString(s)
    C.print_str(cs)
    C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
}

func main() {
    str1 := "hi how are you\n"
    Print(str1)
}
```

myTest.h

```
void print_str(char *s);
```

myTest.c

```
#include "stdio.h"

void print_str(char *s)
{
    printf("%s\n", s?s:"nil");
}
```

While compiling, I am getting the following error:

```
> go build myTest.go

# command-line-arguments
/tmp/go-build989557946/b001/_x002.o: In function `_cgo_4c80c9e4eaf0_Cfunc_print_str':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:49: undefined reference to `print_str'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Go version is:

```
> go version
go version go1.10 linux/amd64
```

Comment: You're calling `go build` with a single file, so it's only going to build a single file. You should be building "packages", see [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: How did you fix your problem? I'm having the same issue...

Comment: Answering myself:
according to https://golang.org/doc/code.html the important part is to use "main" as the package name if the .go file should be executed (= conatins the "main" function). That was my mistake!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> $ go help build
> usage: go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
>
> Build compiles the packages named by the import paths,
> along with their dependencies, but it does not install the results.
>
> If the arguments to build are a list of .go files, build treats
> them as a list of source files specifying a single package.
>
> << SNIP>>
> ```

---

> If the arguments to build are a list of .go files, build treats them
>   as a list of source files specifying a single package.

```
> go build myTest.go
```

builds file `myTest.go`

Run

```
> go build
```

Comment: In my case the package is called "main". I had to create a folder called "main" and put all of the files there so I could "go build -o myExecutable main".
Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Correction the previous comment. The command is "go build -o myExecutable ./main"