# CGo doesn't compile C files

Tags: go, cgo, go-build

I have a really simple setup: A .go file (*test.go*) and a .c file (*PMDK.c*). I include the .c file in Go as follows:

*test.go*:

```
package main

/*
#include "PMDK.c"
#cgo pkg-config: libpmem
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.helloWorld()
}
```

When I run *go run test.go*, it builds for exactly one time. Whatever changes I do to *PMDK.c*, my program has the exact same behavior every time.

I also tried *go build test.go*, which leads to the same result.
Finally , following [CGo not compiling C files in same directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556169/cgo-not-compiling-c-files-in-same-directory), I just did *go build*. This didn't work, since I had to create a .mod file (*go build test.go*). Then, the problem was that the three functions in *PMDK.c* (*helloWorld* and two others) were supposedly defined multiple times.
I can't make it build my changes.
By the way, if I copy/move the source files to another directory and build them there, the changes apply (only for once, again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that your setup is wrong: your Go code should `#include`, in the Cgo prefix, only the *headers for* any C code you want compiled separately.  For instance:

```golang
package main

/*
#include "pmdk.h"
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.helloWorld()
}
```

You *can* put C code into the prefix:

```golang
package main

/*
#include <stdio.h>
void helloWorld() {
        printf("hello world from C\n");
}
*/
import "C"

...
```

But if you put your C code into a *separate file* (`prog.c`, etc.), you should create a small *header file* that simply declares each function, and `#include` that header file from both the C code and the Go code.<sup>1</sup>

Running:

```
go build
```

will then compile the C code if it has changed, and build the Go code if it has changed, and link together the two as appropriate.  If you `#include` the C code directly into the Go package, as you did, `go build` will both build the C code *and* build the Go code *that includes the C code*, which is why you get the duplicate definitions.

Whatever C code you embed in the Cgo header should appear nowhere else.  This is a good place to put small "plumbing adapters", if you have some existing C code that mostly works with Go, but needs some tweaks.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a general technique in C for making sure that the header file *declarations* of functions agree with the C source *definition* of the same functions.  That is, the header `fifth.h` might say:

```c
void func(int arg1, char *arg2);
```

and, separately, the C code will read:

```c
#include "fifth.h"

void func(int zorg, char *evil) {
    // ...
}
```

and the C compiler will check that the declaration matches the definition.